# Сортировка строк матрицы по количеству одинаковых элементов в них

Tags: c++, сортировка, матрицы

Как отсортировать строки целочисленной прямоугольной матрицы по возрастанию количества одинаковых элементов в каждой строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил такой путь:

1. Подсчитать ключ сортировки (т. е., количество одинаковых элементов) для каждой строки матрицы.
2. Отсортировать стандартным алгоритмом `std::sort` множество пар из индекса строки и полученного в предыдущем пункте ключа.
3. Применил полученную перестановку индексов к исходной матрице.

Преимущества метода перед стандартным подходом:

- Не нужно много раз подсчитывать ключ (это дорогая операция для больших матриц)
- Каждая строка переставляется минимально необходимое количество раз (это тоже дорогая операция для больших матриц)

Удачи в реализации и отладке!